# SQL : Flag multiple records with duplicate values but in alternate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sas

I have a problem. I have SQL table which has two variables but duplicated alternatively.
So if we have a table

```
A_ID   OTHER_ID   
1111      2222   
2222      1111    
0000      0101  
3333      5555   
5555      3333
```

I want a unique table

```
A_ID   OTHER_ID       
1111    2222          
0000    0101   
3333    5555
```

Or,

```
A_ID   OTHER_ID  FINAL_ID   
1111    2222     2222      
2222    1111     2222          
0000    0101     0101        
3333    5555     3333     
5555    3333     5555
```

Thanks.

Comment: Actually i require to do this is sas, raised this just to see how you work this out is sql.

Comment: What if your data source has a record like `( 1111, 5678 )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data dat;
    input A_ID $ OTHER_ID $;
    datalines;                      
1111      2222   
2222      1111    
0000      0101  
3333      5555   
5555      3333
;

proc sql;
    create table temp as
    select A_ID, OTHER_ID, 
    case 
        when (A_ID<OTHER_ID) then cat(A_ID,OTHER_ID)
        when (OTHER_ID<A_ID) then cat(OTHER_ID,A_ID)
        end as key
    from dat
    order by A_ID;
quit;

data final;
    retain A_ID OTHER_ID;
    set temp;
    by key;
    if first.key;
run;
```

The table temp creates a key variable which is the eight-digit concatenation of A_ID and OTHER_ID once they are sorted numerically. Then the distinct combinations can be found by looking at this key variable.

The table temp looks like this:

```
Obs A_ID OTHER_ID key 
1 0000 0101 0000 0101 
2 1111 2222 1111 2222 
3 2222 1111 1111 2222 
4 3333 5555 3333 5555 
5 5555 3333 3333 5555
```

Comment: Nice logic. Great. But if they are character values instead of numeric, how can we handle that?

Comment: Perfect ! Would love to get your help in future. :)

Comment: I actually made the code work for character values since the example had numbers with many leading zeros. Try changing some values to characters - it will still work.

Comment: Don't you think using "(A_ID<OTHER_ID)" for character values is wrong.

Comment: It will still sort them, albeit this time lexicographically.

Answer (score 0):

For first output:-

```
/***In SQL server***/    
CREATE TABLE TABLES2(A_ID varchar(20), OTHER_ID varchar(20));

INSERT INTO TABLES2 VALUES('1111','2222');
INSERT INTO TABLES2 VALUES('2222','1111');
INSERT INTO TABLES2 VALUES('0000','0101');
INSERT INTO TABLES2 VALUES('3333','5555');
INSERT INTO TABLES2 VALUES('5555','3333');


select A_ID ,OTHER_ID 
from
(
Select distinct A_ID ,OTHER_ID,(lag(OTHER_ID) over (order by A_ID)) as col_lag
from tables2
) a
where A_ID <> col_lag or col_lag is null


 /****OUTPUT****/
A_ID    OTHER_ID
0000    0101
1111    2222
3333    5555

select A_ID ,OTHER_ID 
from
(
Select distinct A_ID ,OTHER_ID,(lag(OTHER_ID) over (order by A_ID)) as col_lag
from tables2
) a
where A_ID <> col_lag or col_lag is null    


/***In SAS with same logic using lag function***/

data have;
    input A_ID  OTHER_ID ;
    datalines;                   
1111      2222   
2222      1111  
0000      0101 
3333      5555  
5555      3333  
;

data have;
set have;
col_lag =lag(OTHER_ID);
run;

/* if character columns*/
proc sql;
create table answer as
select A_ID ,OTHER_ID from
(
Select distinct A_ID ,OTHER_ID,col_lag
from have
) a
where col_lag not= A_ID or col_lag not= ' ';
quit;

/* if numeric columns*/
proc sql;
create table answer as
select A_ID ,OTHER_ID from
(
Select distinct A_ID ,OTHER_ID,col_lag
from have
) a
where col_lag not= A_ID or col_lag not=.;
quit;
```

Hope this helps:-)

Comment: Help me understand this part of the query. When col_lag is not present in the inner table  then   how can it be used as a where condition for the outer query.
"create table answer as
select A_ID ,OTHER_ID from
(
Select distinct A_ID ,OTHER_ID 
from have
) a
where col_lag not= A_ID or col_lag not= ' ';
quit;"

Comment: @G.arima thanks for pointing that out. Due to some weird reason missed it while copy pasting. Fixed it now